How to validate Spring RestController generic response
I'm trying to validate the response of the Spring REST Controller method.
Response is a parameterized type JsonWrapper<MyDto>
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@Validated
public class MyController {

    @GetMapping("{myId}")
    public JsonWrapper<MyDto> get(@PathVariable Long myId) {
        MyDto myDto = myService.getById(myId);
        return JsonWrapperFactory.ok(myDto);
    }
}


@Validated
public class JsonWrapper<T> {

    @Valid
    private T data;
}

public class MyDto {

    @NotNull
    private Long id;

    @NotEmpty
    private String message;
}

However validation of the response doesn't occur.
How can I validate parameterized type response?

Finally I found a solution. My mistake was that I didn't annotate controller method with @Valid.
@Validated over the controller class and @Valid over the data field in JsonWrapper class are needed too.
@GetMapping("{myId}")
@Valid
public JsonWrapper<MyDto> get(@PathVariable Long myId) {
    MyDto myDto = myService.getById(myId);
    return JsonWrapperFactory.ok(myDto);
}


I suggest to try with ResponseBody<[Put Entity Type Here] like this example:
ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body([your object to return into request body])

